# Why can't I execute airdump-ng mon0 after installing aircrack-ng?

Tags: aircrack-ng

I'm new to Ubuntu but I'm trying to get hang of it for a while now, been trying to install `aircrack-ng` on the 12.04 LTS but I'm stuck now. This is a snapshot of where my problems got started. Please help me with all options possible. If I should start everything all over, let me know with a vivid step-by-step procedure. I will be very grateful for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You did not put your wireless card into monitor mode, you misspelt `wlan0` and typed `wlann0` instead. As a result, the monitor interface `mon0` was not created.

So, do `airmon-ng start wlan0`.